# Is there a way for the Ace editor to preserve indentation upon a newline?

Tags: bespin, ace-editor

Would be helpful for editing a YAML or Python, for example.

Comment: When I load the Python document in the demo from the current sources, it does preserve indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation preservation is configured in the language mode (see f.e. [`getNextLineIndent`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/javascript.js)), if you don't have this it probably is due to no language mode selected. Change the language mode by:

```
<script src="src/mode-python.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
var PythonMode = require("ace/mode/python").Mode;
editor.getSession().setMode(new PythonMode());
</script>
```

To get syntax highlighting and auto-indent.